# Links passing under a div still clickable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm using a div to render a shadow over some content that is passing underneath. The problem is that when the content if located under the div with the shadow you can no longer interact with the div under the shadow.

Is there any way to work around this?

Thanks

Comment: any code? or do we have to guess at how you did it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`pointer-events` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/css/pointer-events) in Firefox and Chrome/Safari to let mouse clicks pass through elements.  In other browsers you'd have to detect the clicks and pass them through yourself.

Comment: pointer-events:none seems to just prevent mouse events from occuring at all for me in chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Try using z-index property in css for the div's..

Example, Div under shadow is having z-index greater than div on the top

Comment: I want the shadow to be rendered over the text tho, if it's on a higher z-index the shadow will be under the text.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just set the background colour of the text to be semi-transparent?

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AWbnt/) example.

I'm not sure if this is the functionality you're looking for. Maybe if you posted some of your source code...